# $|A-\lambda I|$ and $|\lambda I-A|$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that both can be used to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors as

$Ax=\lambda x\iff Ax-\lambda x=0 \iff x(A-\lambda I)=0\iff  |A-\lambda I|=0$ And in the same way $Ax=\lambda x\iff 0=\lambda x-AX \iff x(\lambda I-Ax)=0\iff  |\lambda I-A|=0$

So the different between the two will be by plus/minus sign in the characteristic polynomial?

for example $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 &1 \\
0 & 3 &0\\
1 &0 &2
\end{pmatrix}$ will be $f_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-3)^{2}(\lambda-1)$ for $|\lambda I-A|$ and $f_A(\lambda)=-(\lambda-3)^{2}(\lambda-1)$ for  $|A-\lambda I|$

Comment: Yes, because $|A-\lambda I|=(-1)^n|\lambda I-A|$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ (for some natural number $n$) matrix and $\lambda$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the only different between them is the plus/minus sign of the characteristic polynomial. However this is not an issue because eigenvalues are solutions of the equation $p(x)=0$ and if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, then $p(x)$ and $-p(x)$ have the same roots. So both methods work.